# New method for injecting dll in chrome?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, winapi, dll, dll-injection

I have tried an [old example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3d5085c2-5506-43f8-b2f4-992f96a3ce22/security-protection-on-google-chrome?forum=windowssecurity) of how to inject a dll in Chrome however when I use `CreateProcess` to open chrome.exe it seems to immediately shutdown and restart with a new pid contrary to the one stored in the `dwProcessId` member of the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure I pass to `CreateProcess`. I have also tried making a function to calculate the offset of `LoadLibraryA` relative to the base loading address of kernel32.dll in the remote process. I have tried this on other processes like notepad.exe and  was successful so I know my funciton for finding the function in other processes even though they do not load kernel32 at the preferred address. Whenever I try to load the dll with `LoadLibraryA` in chrome, chrome immediately crashes which I think is a security feature. I am stumped and have been trying to figure this out for around a month and a half. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Too broad and not a good fit for SO. Voting to close and moving on...please see the help section on [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious How is asking a question about how to go about programmatically injecting a dll too broad when I've specified specifically how I've tried to do it and the exact process in which I am attempting to do so on? There are legitimate uses for it and there are many programmers who do it, specifically to chrome, for purposes of a network communication hub and so forth. Since this is more programming oriented than security I figured it would be better suited for a site like SO that focuses on programming solutions.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Did you look at the link I put for _old example_? uTorrent and other applications do the same to avoid having to be issued digital certificates.

Comment: Yeah, hijacking a digital certificate not issued to you for purposes the owner likely does not condone is _legitimate_.

Comment: no any problem inject dll to chrome, and digital certificate here not related at all. and LoadLibraryA have same adress in all processes(kernel32 loaded at same base always)

Comment: @RbMm Not with ALSR. It's the reason I had to make a function to claculate the RVA of `LoadLibraryA` in a remote process relative to the address at which kernel32 loaded. But that's botched anyways because of how chrome sandboxes its threads and terminates them as soon as it suspects it's been injected.

Comment: @ProgrammingLad - you mistake.  ALSR here absolute not related. i say that in all processes in system kernel32.dll loaded at same base. so enough get this address from self process and it will be valid for any another

Comment: @ProgrammingLad and about chrome you mistake, no any problem inject dll to it. all work

Comment: @RbMm I have tried different ways of injecting the DLL into chrome and every time it fails even though it works in every other application I do it in. And now I'm confused, if kernel32 is loaded to the same address in every process why isn't the pointer for `LoadLibraryA` returned from `GetProcAddress` valid when I try to call `CreateRemoteThread` on it without getting the RVA of the function?

Comment: @ProgrammingLad - so you simply mistake. LoadLibraryA have same address in process in system (of course exist 2 address in x64 system - 32 and 64 bit)

Comment: @ProgrammingLad - and every time it fails - because every time you do some mistakes

Comment: @RbMm What do you mean on x64 two addresses exist? Do you mean it can be represented with either a 64 or 32 bit pointer?

Comment: @ProgrammingLad - what your level of knowledge at all ?!? exist 64 bit kernel32.dll and 32 bit kernel32.dll in x64 system. if your process have same bits(32 or 64) with target - you have the same dll and address. if different bits - different addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely if it's not working it's something you're doing wrong. Whether it be trying to inject a 64 bit dll into a 32 bit process or vice versa. Make sure your dll is the same bit architecture as Chrome. If Chrome is in `Program Files(x86)` then that means it's 32 bit and you need to make a 32 bit dll for it. And in some other questions you asked you said you made a function to calculate the address of `LoadLibraryA` in other processes but since you map it into your own process you can only find the address of it in processes that have the same bit architecture. Post your code.

Comment: Compiled them both to 32 bit and IT WORKED!!!! YOU'RE AWESOME!!!!!